# Make innerjoin in linq to sql(Compiled query)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql

my .cs code for compiled query is

```
public static Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, IQueryable<editor_j_inf>>
editordetail1 = CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext db, int a) =>
             from p1 in db.editor_j_infs
             where p1.ed_journal_id == a
             orderby p1.editor_id descending
             select p1);   //Its my precompile process
```

what shall i do if i want to do innerjoin between 2 table in this compiler query

say 1 table name is editor_j_inf and another is editor_j_inf1.How to make inner join between this 2 table

I have tried putting

```
 public static Func<DataClassesDataContext, string, int, int, IQueryable<A>>
  getjournal2 = CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext db, string a, int b, int c) =>
         from p in db.editor_j_infs
         join p1 in db.editor_regs on p.editor_id equals p1.editor_id
         where p.j_email == a && p1.confirm1 == b && p1.denied == c
         orderby p.ed_journal_id descending
         select new A{Title= p.j_title,EditorId= p.editor_id,EditorId1=p.ed_journal_id });


Public class A
{ 
    public string Title {get;set;} 
    public int EditorId {get;set;}
    public int EditorId1 { get; set;} 
}
 public void getjournals()
{
    string email="abc@gmail.com";    
    var rr1 = getjournal2(db, email,1,0).ToList();

    var rrlist = rr1.ToList();

    if (rrlist.Count() != 0)
    {
        DataList1.DataSource = rr1;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Now how to make this bind with datalist?

Comment: Your returning type is `IQueryable<editor_j_inf>` but your query selects `p.j_title`, which is a `String` I assume. Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: I think so you are right, because when i used to write only select p; instead of select new { p.j_title }; its working well. so what shall i do?

Comment: and if i want both p,p1 in select i.e. select p,p1; than what shall i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make returning type and actual return correspond. If you need a `string` make `Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, IQueryable<string>>`

and finish query with

`select new {p.j_title}` or even `select p.j_title`. If you need `editor_j_inf` then leave function declaration as is and finish query with `select p`

Comment: and if i want both p,p1 in select i.e. select p,p1; than what shall i have to do?

Comment: If you want to combine result from p and p1, you need to create some intermediate class with field you need from p and p1, make it a returning type and create it in select statement. Example: `class A { public string Title {get;set;} public int EditorId {get;set;}` then `Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, IQueryable<A>>` and `select new A { Title = p.j_title, EditorId = p1.editor_id }`. Something like this.

Comment: Make a class public: `public class A...`

Comment: That's what we are doing, but we'll have classes, not tables. Try to make your class public.

Comment: can u answer me for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674989/linq-to-sql-storeprocedure-vs-3tier-architecture

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
from p1 in db.editor_j_inf
join p2 in db.editor_j_inf1
on new { p1.ed_journal_id , p1.column2}
equals new { p2.ed_journal_id , p2.column2}
select p1.column1 + " " + p1.column2;
```